# Intersection of Turing Machines Languages

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Given a Turing Machine A and a Turing Machine B, how can I know if the intersection of the Languages of both Turing Machines is non empty?

L(A) $\cap$ L(B) $\neq$ 0

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this problem is undecidable! See: [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Formal_statement).

Comment: Is there a way to prove it without using Rice's Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30077/decidability-of-empty-intersection-of-two-languages-accepted-by-turing-machines) thread!

Comment: Thank you! I answered the thread, can you check if my approach to solve the problem is correct?